# small string optimization(SSO) and move semantics

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

```
std::string test = "small_string";

std::string test2_1 = test;   // line 1

std::string test2_2 = std::move(test); // line 2
```

hi, i am curious about which version of string create is fast. `test2_1` or `test2_2`?

I was looking into the implement on VC++ version of `std::string`, found out that `test2_1` version will call `memcpy(_First1, _First2, _Count))` and `test2_2` will call `memmove(_First1, _First2, _Count))`, and I just wonder which one is better if I want my code run faster.

==============================================================

hi, i just do some test, and there has something that i can't understand...here is my test code:

```
{
    Timer t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        char s[] = "small_string";
        char t[10];

        memcpy(&t, &s, 10);
        //std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "test, memcpy: " << t.elapsed() << " second" << std::endl;
}


{
    Timer t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        char s[] = "small_string";
        char t[10];
        memmove(&t, &s, 10);
       // std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "test, memmove: " << t.elapsed() << " second" << std::endl;
}


{
    Timer t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){

        std::string test = "small_string";
        std::string test2_1 = test;   // line 1
    }

    std::cout << "test, str copy: " << t.elapsed() << " second" << std::endl;
}


{
    Timer t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){

        std::string test = "small_string";
        std::string test2_2 = std::move(test); // line 2
    }
    std::cout << "test, str move: " << t.elapsed() << " second" << std::endl;
}
```

and result is:(debug build)

test, memcpy: 0.0090005 second

test, memmove: 0.0110006 second

test, str copy: 4.92528 second

test, str move: 4.52926 second

I know memcpy should faster than memmove, and my first two test case prove that. But the result of std::string is different...move version is faster than copy version. I didn't know why even looking into implementation of std::string, i didn't find anything that can convince me that this should happen.

=======================================================

result:(release build)

test, memcpy: 0 second

test, memmove: 0.0080004 second

test, str copy: 0.0330019 second

test, str move: 0.0290017 second

Comment: Move semantics should perform better. But there is only one way to find that out: benchmark it.

Comment: How about googling for something like "memmove vs memcpy"? Or write a benchmark and measure the performance on a few different computers?

Comment: Does this really matter? Small strings are small; their assignment is going to be fast either way.

Comment: Just remember that if you're constantly `std::move`'ing, you'll also incur the cost of a deallocation. Whereas with small strings, it will just be a (16)? byte copy

Comment: @Alejandro As youre moving, there wont be any deallocations.

Comment: hi, I just give a test and edit my question, but result is weird...

Comment: @Michael `std::move` has nothing to do with "`memmove` vs `memcpy`"...

Comment: I will take your word that you looked at the implementations and found `memcpy` and `memmove`. The only conclusion to take from your tests is that the time taken isn't dominated by `memcpy` and `memmove`, but is taken by something else. Look at the rest of the code and see what the difference is.

Comment: @rubenvb: See the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: @Michael right. Sorry. You're right. an SSO implementation will probably call `memmove`.

Comment: @MSalters I once worked with some code that used Microsoft's `CString` where every string was not only short but was constant size. It was unacceptably slow, so I wrote my own fixed-size string class with a compatible interface and it sped up by 5x if I remember correctly.

Comment: Could you try to move this line std::string test = "small_string"; out of the loop? also you could take the chance to change it to: std::string test("small_string");

Comment: Since you didn't state it explicitly, it must be asked: did you test an optimised build? i.e. release build?

Comment: @ dau_sama hi, because std::string test2_2 = std::move(test); will move content of std::string test into test2_2, so if I move it outside the loop, test baseline will become different.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely  i test in the debug build.

Comment: @dorgon then a downvote for you. Asking about tiny performance differences in unoptimized code is pointless, and tells you nothing useful.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely but release build shows same result..., i will update the result of release build.

Comment: I find the difference in time between string operation and memcpy huge: more than 4 seconds compared to 1/100s. My guess is that you compiled as a 32 bit application, so small string optimization happens with strings having 10 characters or less. Your "small_string" has 12, so will not be optimized. So what you see is time spent in allocating memory, not copying it

Comment: @ Frederic Lachasse VC++ implementation of SSO is fiex into 16 byte, here is implement  of std::string : enum
     { // length of internal buffer, [1, 16]
  _BUF_SIZE = 16 / sizeof (value_type) < 1 ? 1
   : 16 / sizeof (value_type)};

Answer (score 1):

> hi, i am curious about which version of string create is fast. test2_1 or test2_2?

This seems like a clear example of premature optimization. The two forms aren't even equivalent, so asking which is faster is ridiculous.

Write code that does the right thing, and only worry about silly micro-optimizations if there's a performance problem.

Line 1 leaves `test` unchanged, so it keeps the same value. Line 2 modifies `test` leaving it in an unspecified state.

If your code doesn't depend on the value of `test` after creating the other string, then you should use `std::move` because it expresses the desired semantics (and if the string doesn't fit in the small-string buffer it will *definitely* be faster).

If your code cares about the value of `test` afterwards then do not use `std::move`, just do a copy instead.

Benchmarking the difference between apples and oranges is a waste of time.

Benchmarking tiny differences in a debug build is a massive waste of time. If you care about performance you need to enable optimizations.

Comment: hi, I know the performance between this two is small, but i am just curious, and expect copy version should faster than move version, but the test result is different...